# File created with append mode in python 3.7.4 0

Tags: python-3.7

I tried the below code with pycharm IDE and found that file is being created for append mode.

As we learn in course lecture that file will be created only with write `mode ='w'`

```
with open('xyz.txt',mode= 'a') as xyz_file:

  xyz_file.write('This file is created in append mode')

with open('xyz.txt',mode= 'r') as xyz_file:
    print(xyz_file.read())
```

I was aware that there is no file that exists with the name xyz.txt in my python file path. yet with the above code, it is created and the text appended.

Answer (score -1):

The python `open()` command will create the file if the mode is `'w'`, `'a'`, or `'x'`.

I believe that if you want to be able to write in a file but still error if the file is not created, the `'r+'` mode will do that.